# who knows how to draw graphic primitives in turn

Tags: java

say at first rectangle and then a line for example

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Canvas;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

//class MyCanvas extends JComponent {   

class MyCanvas extends Canvas {
   public void paint(Graphics g) {
      g.fillRect(20, 20, 500, 500);
   }
}

class Linie extends MyCanvas {
   public void paint(Graphics g) {
      g.setColor(new Color(0, 255, 0));
      g.drawLine(30, 40, 300, 100);

   }
}

public class LinieUndRec {
   public static void main(String[] a) {
      JFrame window = new JFrame();
      window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      window.setBounds(100, 100, 800, 800);
      window.getContentPane().add(new MyCanvas());
      window.getContentPane().add(new Linie());
      window.setVisible(true);
   }
}
```

this code draws only a line 
how to draw a rectangle and a line

Comment: Could you include (links to) what image you get and what image you expect

Comment: The code draws both, but the Linie canvas happens to overlay the MyCanvas. You use *one* canvas to draw everthing, not multiple.

Comment: the programme must draw both rectangle and a line but it draws only a line

Answer (score 3):

In your implementation of the `Linie` class, you're providing code for the `paint` method. This *replaces* the code of the `paint` method on the `MyCanvas` class, because `Linie extends MyCanvas`.

So, when you call `paint()` on an instance of `Linie` only the code in the `Linie.paint()` method is run, not both. If you want it to run both, add do this:

```
class Linie extends MyCanvas {
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);   // This will draw the rectangle from the parent class,
                          // then render the line below

        g.setColor(new Color(0,255,0));
        g.drawLine(30,40, 300, 100);
    }
}
```

As a side note, even though the code above should work, **type inheritance isn't meant to solve this kind of problem**. I'm just trying to provide an answer to the code as provided.

If you really want to draw a rectangle followed by a line, then call `.paint()` on an object that represents a rectangle, then call `.paint()` on an object that represents a line, one after the other. What you have here is...well, really bad code (that's okay if you're new to Java - we were all new once). You're using inheritance to accomplish what would be done by just calling two `.paint()` commands after each other.

Also as [@Durandal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/352131/durandal) points out, you can use a single canvas to do all drawings. You don't need one canvas per drawing operation. Think of a `Canvas` as a surface you can draw on, like a piece of paper or, well, like a painter's canvas. And think of the drawing operations as instructions of what to do in order to construct a painting. Generally speaking, you must draw things in the background first, followed by things in the foreground. The result is that drawing that happens first is covered up by drawing that happens later.

Comment: do you mean window.getContentPane().add(new MyCanvas.paint());?